# Nagra SD reviews?

Tags: field-recording, field-recorder

Anyone test out the nagra sd yet? Thoughts? I've only found one review online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I haven't recorded with one, but I'm interested in them too. I'm also curious to hear any reports. I imagine at that price point, most folks in this group would opt for a SD 702. But the convenience of a high quality hand held is really nice. I love traveling with one.

I picked one up once at a trade show...it's very small and well built with a metal case. Nagra certainly has a great reputation, building quality sounding gear. Although with the strength of the Swiss Franc compared to the US dollar, their stuff is probably a bit overpriced here in the US.

From my online research, folks are saying that it sounds nice, especially if you upgrade and buy the green banded "high quality" stereo mic. Here'a [gearslutz thread](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/remote-possibilities-acoustic-music-location-recording/631785-nagra-sd.html) with a bit of useful info.

It has a slick adaptor cable that allows you to plug in external mics. But that feature is also the biggest downfall of this machine. It doesn't supply phantom power. If it did, buying this would be a no brainer to me, considering it's the size of a deck of cards. It's pretty clear that Nagra designed this feature primarily for news journalists walking around with a dynamic mic.